# Как переназначить переменную?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код, в котором простая игра по отгадыванию числа. Здесь есть функция, которая выполняет запросы и если игрок выбрал правильное число, то игра должна завершиться, а число смениться на другое. Как завершить игру, я сам знаю, но вот сменить число на другое никак не получается, программа не даёт:

```
import random

command = input()
stop_word = 'stop'
next_start_word = 'start'
next_step_word = 'go'

collection_words = [command, stop_word, next_start_word, next_step_word]

min_number = 1
max_number = 100
specified_number = random.randint(min_number, max_number)

collection_number = [specified_number, min_number, max_number]

def Start_Game(collection_number):
    print("Введите число от ", min_number, "до", max_number)
    print(specified_number)
    now_number = int(input())
    if now_number < specified_number:
        print("число меньше заданного!")
    elif now_number > specified_number:
        print("Число больше заданного!")
    else:
        print("Вы угадали!")
        specified_number = random.randint(min_number, max_number)

def Main_Body_Programm(collection_words):
    while command != stop_word:
        if command == stop_word:
            break
        elif command == next_start_word:
            Start_Game(collection_number)
        else:
            print("Текущая комманда не опознана, попробуйте ещё.")
            break

Main_Body_Programm(collection_words)
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте вычисление `specified_number` и `collection_number` перед вызовом новой игры:

```
def Main_Body_Programm(collection_words):
    while command != stop_word:
        if command == stop_word:
            break
        elif command == next_start_word:
            specified_number = random.randint(min_number, max_number)
            collection_number = [specified_number, min_number, max_number]

            Start_Game(collection_number)
        else:
            print("Текущая комманда не опознана, попробуйте ещё.")
            break
```

Comment: возможно оно и работает, но у меня пишет тоже самое - "local variable 'specified_number' referenced before assignment"

Comment: Нужно ещё разворачивать `collection_number` в начале функции `Start_Game` обратно в значения составляющих её переменных: `specified_number, min_number, max_number = collection_number`

Answer (score 2):

Нужно предупредить питон что переменная не локальная или глобальная при таких ошибках

```
def Start_Game(collection_number):
    nonlocal specified_number
...
```